# How many binary algebraic structures are there on the set $\{a,b\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Since a binary algebraic structure is a binary operation with its set $S$, would the number of binary structures on the set $\{a,b\} = 2^2 = 4$?

Comment: The range has 2 elements, the domain has 4. Conclusions?

Comment: Wait, so I'm allowed to use any subset of this set to map to this set?

Comment: If that's the case, it would be 4^2 = 8?

Comment: You would have $2^4$.  For each element of the domain, you have $2$ choices.  So, that's $2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2$ possibilities.  That is as long as there are no conditions on the binary operation.

Comment: Just for reference, $4^2$ is not $8$.

Comment: In general, the number of possible functions from a set $A$ to a set $B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$.

Comment: Haha, yeah, I meant to type 4 * 2. I would hope I know that by the time I'm at the end of my degree

Comment: But if you have 2 choices for each element, wouldn't it be just  2^2: 1 element 2 choices + other element which has 2 choices?

Comment: Since 16 is still a fairly small integer, you might try actually listing all possible binary operations. This corresponds to making a 2x2 matrix, with 4 entries (in effect, a Cayley table).